# Minimatch exclude pattern in VSTS publish task

Tags: azure-devops, minimatch

I've been wrestling with getting this minimatch exclude pattern to work.

The ****\src!(packages)** pattern works as expected but I need to also exclude web.template.config files under the src directory.  I've tried several things including ****\src!(packages|*Web.template*.config)**

Can anyone help or point me to a good way of troubleshooting this?  I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work,

- I added the **Copy Files** task
- Applied the minimatch filter to the **Copy Files** task
- Used the **Publish Task** to copy the entire $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) directory.

The minimatch filter is as follows...

```
**/src/**/!(*eb.*emplate*.config)
!**/packages{,/**}
```